# How to solve $\,a^{100}\equiv 2,\ a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod{73}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I know that
 $a^{100}\equiv 2\pmod{73}$, $a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod{73}$

then find $a\equiv x\pmod{73}$

I can write $a^{101}\equiv a^{100+1}\equiv 2x\equiv 69 $, then $x\equiv 71\pmod{73}$ I am not so sure is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, but we must justify  $\,2x\equiv 69\iff x\equiv 71\pmod{\!73}\,$ and also verify the root.

$\quad  \bmod 73\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{a^{100}\equiv 2}\ \Rightarrow\ 69\equiv \color{#0a0}{a^{100}} a\equiv  \color{#0a0}2a\!\iff\! 2a\equiv 69\equiv -4 \color{#c00}{\!\iff\!} a\equiv -2\equiv 71$

It's valid to  $\color{#c00}{{\rm cancel}\ 2}\,$ since, by Bezout, elements coprime to $73$ are invertible so cancellable (by multiplying by the inverse).  Because our first arrow $(\Rightarrow)$ is unidirectional, we need to verify it reverses, i.e. $\,a\equiv -2\,$ satisfies $\,a^{100}\equiv 2.\,$ i.e. $\, (-2)^{100}\equiv 2,\,$ which is true iff $\,2^{99}\equiv 1,\,$ again by cancelling $2.\,$ Let $n$ be the order of $2.\,$ By Fermat $\,2^{72}\equiv 1\,$ so $\,n\mid 72.\,$ Therefore

$$\,2^{99}\equiv 1\iff n\mid 99\iff n\mid 99,72\iff n\mid (99,72)=9(11,8)=9\iff 2^9\equiv 1\qquad$$

which is true: $\, 2^9\equiv 2^3 2^6\equiv 8(-9)\equiv 1.\,$ So $\,a\equiv -2\,$ is the *unique* solution of the congruences.

**Remark** $ $ Alternatively we can employ the above modular calculations within a Euclidean gcd calculation, using the gcd property $\,(x,y) = (x,\,y\bmod x)$ as
 sketched below for any odd $n$

$$\begin{align} &\ \  n\mid a^{101}\!+\!4,\,a^{100}\!-2\\[.3em] 
\iff\, n = &\ (n,\,a^{101}\!+\!4,\,a^{100}\!-2)\\ 
 =&\ (n,\  2a\, +\, 4,\,a^{100}\!-2)\\ 
 =&\ (n,\ \ \,a\  +\, 2,\,a^{100}\!-2)\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ (n,2)=1\ \ \\ 
 =&\ (n,\ \ \, a\,+\ 2,\,(-\!2)^{100}\!-2)\\[.3em]
\iff\qquad &n\, \mid \ \ \, a\,+\ 2,\,(-\!2)^{100}-2\end{align}\qquad\qquad  $$

Comment: Above I proved inline $\, \large 2^j\equiv 1\equiv 2^k\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{(j,k)}\equiv 1\,$  for $\, j,k = 99,72.\,$ If you already know that then you can simply invoke that lemma. It can be proved as above or by the Bezout identity for the gcd,

Answer (score 0):

==== 2nd answer that assumes some basic knowledge of modular arithmetic====

As $73$ is prime every equivalence class (except $0$) has a multiplicative inverse and we can solve by equations by division.

So if $a^{100}\equiv 2 \pmod{73}$ and $a^{101} \equiv 69\pmod{73}$ then $a \equiv 69*2^{-1}\equiv (-4)*2^{-1}\equiv -2\pmod {73}$.

But this assumes that $a^{100} \equiv 2 \pmod{73}$ and $a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod {73}$ has a solution in the first place.

[Notice if we said $a^{k}\equiv 2; a^{k+1}\equiv 69$ for *any* $k$ we'd have gotten the same answer even though it's obviously not true that $(-2)^k \equiv 2$ for all $k$.]

If $(-2)^{100} \equiv 2$ then $(-2)^{99} \equiv -1$ and $(-2)^{198}\equiv 1$.  By Fermat's Little Theorem $(-2)^{72}\equiv 1 \pmod {73}$ so *if* $(-2)^{198} \equiv 1$ then $(-2)^{\gcd(198, 72) = 18} \equiv 1$.  This would implies $(-2)^9 \equiv \pm 1$.  And as $2^{99} \equiv -1$ this would mean $(-2)^9 \equiv -1 \pmod {73}$.

Well, does it?  $(-2)^9 = -512= -1 - 7*73 \equiv -1 \pmod {73}$.

Thus $(-2)^{99} =((-2)^9)^{11} \equiv (-1)^{11} \equiv -1 \pmod {73}$ and so $a^{100}\equiv -1*-2\equiv 2$ and $a^{101}\equiv 2*(-2)\equiv -4 \equiv 69 \pmod {73}$.

=== first answer which assumes little knowledge of modular arithmetic; but assumes the conditions as given (that $a^{100}\equiv 2$ even *has* a solution and that such a solution would be compatible with $a^{101}\equiv 69$) were God's truth on earth.  ===

$a^{101} = a^{100}\cdot a \equiv (\text{anything that }a^{100}\text{ is equivalent to})\cdot (\text{anything that }a\text{ is equivalent to})\equiv 2\cdot x \pmod {73}$.

And $a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod {73}$.  So $2x \equiv 69 \pmod {73}$ is a correct statement.  That is what you must solve.

You claim out of the blue that $x \equiv 71 \pmod {73}$ but don't expain why.

Well, one intuitive way I can see is $2x \equiv 69 \equiv -4\pmod {73}$ so $x \equiv -2$ or $x \equiv 71 \pmod {73}$ seems a good way of figuring out.

But I have to wonder is $x \equiv 71 \pmod{73}$ then *only* answer.  For example if I had $2*x \equiv 2 \pmod{10}$ then $x \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ is *one* answer but $x \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$ is another.

So $2x \equiv 69 \pmod {73}$ means there is an integer $k$ so that $2x = 69 + 73k$.  So $x = \frac {69 + 73k}2$.  The only way this is possible is if $69 + 73k$ is even which would mean $k$ is odd.  So there is an $m$ so that $k = 2m + 1$ and $x = \frac {69 + 73(2m + 1)}2 = \frac {69+73}2 + 73m = 71 + 73m$ so $x \equiv 71 \pmod{73}$ and that is unique.

[I guess another way of doing $2x \equiv 69 \pmod {73}$ is $2x \equiv 69 \equiv 69+73 \equiv 142 \pmod{73}$ and $x \equiv 71 \pmod{73}$ is a solution.

If we tried to do that with $2x \equiv 2 \pmod {10}$ we'd have there is an $k$ so that $2x = 2 + 10k$ so $x = 1 + 5k$.  We don't know if $k$ is even or odd.  Let $k = 2m + i$ where $i$ might be either $1$ or $0$.  Then $x = 1 + 5(2m + i) = (1 + 5i) + 10m$ so $x \equiv 1 + 5i \pmod{10}$ where if $i =0$ we have $x \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ and if $i = 1$ we have $x \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$ so those are the two answers.

====

So food for thought.

Sometimes you can do $mx \equiv k \pmod{n}$ so $x \equiv \frac {k + j*n}n  \pmod {n}$ for some $j$ to get all solutions.... and sometimes you can't.  Do you have any idea when you can and when you can not?

Comment: That doesn't suffice - we also need to verify that $\,a\equiv -2\,$ actually is a solution - see my answer.

Comment: @fleablood: Just rephrase your first part so say that we can clearly see that $x \equiv -2 \pmod{73}$ is a solution because $2·-2 \equiv 69 \pmod{73}$.

Comment: $2*(-2)\equiv -4\equiv 69$ goes without saying.  The point being is this the only solution?  It clearly is *a* solution.

Comment: @fleablood: I know that, but I was trying to help you allay BD's objection, since you didn't explicitly lay it out in a way that shows it is a solution, though obviously there is no other reason to mention "$2x \equiv -4$" if not for that exact purpose.

Comment: I'm not particularly concerned with Bill Dubuque's objection. If it is valid then he has critiqued my answer and future readers can take it into account.  If it is invalid then... it is invalid.  At any rate I don't see it merits my worrying about a post I made 5 days ago.  I'm not entirely sure I understand the objection though.  If $k = 2a$ then and you have to solve $2x\equiv k$ then $x \equiv a$ is a solution.  That's self evident.  But that part of my post was only exploring an *apparent* way of doing it.  THe *ENTIRE* rest of the post was showing it needs more rigor.

Comment: As BD pointed out in his just-edited answer, he was actually referring to the original question where you need to show that $a^{100} \equiv 2$ if $a \equiv -2$. I missed that as well after looking at all the wrong answers below. And I know the point of your post. After all I stated elsewhere that you have correctly identified the errors, and I upvoted your post.

Comment: @flealood  You should be be concerned because my critique is valid. You claim it "clearly is a solution" but without proof. How does your answer prove that $\,a\equiv -2$ is a solution of the congruences?  In particular where do you prove that it satisfies $\,a^{100}\equiv 2\ ?\ $

Comment: Oh!  I understand your critique now! It's that the claim $a^{100} \equiv 2 \mod 73$ and $a^{101}\equiv 69 \mod 73$ without justification.  I showed that If we take those as given to us by God on High then if $x\equiv 2\mod 73$ and $2x \equiv 69 \mod 73$ then $x \equiv 71 \mod 73$ is one answer (becuase it *is* $2*71\equiv 69 \mod 73$) and I explained why it was the only answer, but I *never* explored whether the claims $a^{100}\equiv 2$ and $a^{101}\equiv 69$ were valid at all.  Oh, well, I wrote this 5 days ago and I'm not changing it now.

Comment: Oh.... for the love of Pete!